# Does JVM GC logging affect the running java process performance + Jruby

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jruby

We are trying to collect the JVM (a jruby process) GC logging since we need to establish few facts.

Found few JVM_OPTIONS over [here](https://medium.com/@richardsondx/everything-you-should-know-about-the-obscure-world-of-jruby-jruby-with-ruby-on-rails-c3c90d8fdeec). But I'm not sure whether using them would affect the Running Java process performance.

So my question is whether doing so (i.e adding the JVM OPTIONS for GC loggings) does affect the running process performance.

Comment: There are many many logging-related options, especially with the new unified logging framework in java9. And instead of asking such a broad question you could simply benchmark your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

When you find yourself in a point where you have to tune the JVM and/or GC, that probably means that your system is having problems handling the load. That means you have to dedicate resources very carefully. First of all, any type of logging means an I/O operation and, of course, this will require processing on many layers of the system. Since your system is having problems handling the load, you don't want to put another straw on the camel, so to speak. If that's the case, just use those logging parameters for detecting the GC issues, and when you're done with them, remove them.

Keep in mind that the level of detail in the output will slightly affect the performance.

If your system is doing fine, and you're just using for academic purposes, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't really agree with what you say here.  Yes, it is true that any logging will have some impact on application performance because it adds additional operations not present without logging.  However, the overhead of some print statements is going to be so small as to not be noticeable compared to the workload of the GC.  If you need to tune the GC it doesn't mean the whole system is struggling.  The JVM may be working hard but the OS may well be under no exceptional load.

Comment: of course it varies with the situation at hand. But what you're saying is only a prediction. But we don't know how the OS is coping with the load. And the client probably have never tested it either. A performance tuning effort shouldn't open systems to untested issues as a principle. So the main idea must be that the whole system is having problems with the load, test all the components, and leave without creating a load which was never there in the first place. One shouldn't take their chances on a matter like this. but it's a personal decision of course.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, yes it does, but not significantly.

See this [link of Red Hat Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/performance_tuning_guide/diagnosing_performance_issues):

> Other than some additional disk I/O activity for writing the log files,enabling garbage collection logging **does not significantly affect server performance**.